# Can SVN authentication/authauthorization configurations be shared between svnserve and http DAV?

Tags: svn, apache

I have an SVN server configured with several repositories which were accessed via svnserve (protocol svn://). They all share the same passwd (and authz) files.

I've successfully configured DAV http (and https) access to the repository via apache. From the svn-book, authentication and authorization are configured via the files defined for AuthUserFile and AuthzSVNAccessFile.

This means, however, that you have to maintain two sets of authentication/authorization files, one for the svn:// protocol and the other for http://. **Is it possible to use a single configuration for both protocols**, so you don't risk having different rules/users/passwords configured?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: No

**Longer answer**: at least user-files for svnserve and DAV are totally different (`user = pass` in plain text vs `user:somehash`), you can share Path-based authorization file

Comment: Yes, the main complication arises precisely from the authentication files, as their format is slightly different (as you pointed out). I was just wondering how people managed this situation, as having two separate authorization files will inevitably lead to problems and inconsistencies.

Comment: @mmalmeida - one server-type, one source of trusted user-data (LDAP/AD/NIS)